# array + n shifting in c++ memory behavior

Tags: c++

I am going through a cpp course and the instructor used the following notation to get a subarray of the current array

```
void f(int arr[], int len) {
    if (len == 0)
        return;
    f(arr + 1, len - 1); // arr + 1 takes a subarray 
    ...
}
```

I wanted to understand how the `arr+1` notation works with regards to memory. Arrays are passed by reference, but when you arr + 1 is a copy of the array from the provided offset created, or does it simply advance some pointer and no extra memory is used?

Comment: `arr` is a pointer to the array. So think in terms of pointer arithmetic.

Comment: `arr` is only a pointer, and it is passed by value. so no array copy happens here.

Comment: Thanks all, I realized array is passed by reference, but didn't think of the implication until you all mentioned that it is just a pointer and "arr + 1" is pointer arithmetic.

Comment: [What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) It starts off as an array, and an array is not a pointer, but as soon at you call that function, Whammo! Array decay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array is pass by pointer when you call in function
[see this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-arrays-are-passed-to-functions-in-cc/)

Answer (score 1):

This is generally avoided in c++, but for learning purposes

`arr + 1` is `arr` starting from the next element in the array. For example

```
char arr[] = "12345";
printf("%s\n", arr + 1); //prints 2345
```

Pointer arithmetic applies, pointer is passed to `printf`. Note that `strlen(arr)` is `5`, while `strlen(arr + 1)` is `4`, this is where you get `len - 1`

`*(arr + 1)` is same as `arr[1]` For example

```
printf("%c\n", *(arr + 1)); //prints 2
printf("%c\n", arr[1]); //prints 2
```

Similar notation with integer arrays

```
int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4};
printf("%d\n", *(arr + 1)); //prints 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah the missing piece for me was that `arr + 1` means move the pointer by 1. Therefore, since it's just passing a value of a pointer + 1, it's not a full array copy, which is what I was worried about, and thus no real extra memory used beyond the pointer + 1 value.

Comment: Yes it's seen as `(pointer + 1)`, pointer arithmetic applies, and "array to pointer decay" as mentioned in the other answer and earlier comments.